Connect to running server in VM in Azure
I have a VM up and running in Azure, and exposed on a bastion.
It has a server running and I would like to connect to that server from my local using a browser.
So, I'm trying to access it using the ip that is indicated in the bastion and virtual network, I'm not being able to connect.
I can access using the Azure interface via the bastion, but I can't use a browser there.
Is there a way to either use an external browser to connect to that server, or use a server when connecting via the Azure interface?

All connections through Azure Bastion are initiated from inside the Portal, and you must use a browser.
You can not use a RDP client over the Internet using bastion. To do so would defeat the security objectives of Azure Bastion.
To connect to a VM over the Internet using an RDP client (not recommended) you would need to give it a public IP and configure any NSGs to allow incoming on TCP port 3389.

I can access via browser in the Azure portal, that's not a problem. But in my VM I have a server running and I'd need to connect to it in a way that I can see the corresponding webpage in a browser, if it has to be done within Azure that won't be a problem. For me the only problem is that's I'm only being able to access using command line commands

Are you saying that you can issue CLI commands, but can't see the desktop of the server VM? What operating system is the server? Can you connect by going to the VM overview page, click Connect->Bastion?

The server is Ubuntu. I'm accessing using the Connect->Bastion, yes

@Carabes Azure Bastion doesn't support remote desktop for Linux VMs, unfortunately. You could perhaps install XRDP on the VM, and use a Windows jump box to get to it from inside the same VNet. Other than this your only option is to install XRDP and expose it to Internet with a public IP, maybe set the rdp port to a non standard port (not 3389) to hide it, and if you can specify a single or list of allowed IP addresses then add them to a NSG to filter connections.

what if I try to use just a Virtual Machine in Azure, running Ubuntu inside, and try to connect to it using my local Mac? Would that be feasible @Architect Jamie?

@Carabes Without exposing the Ubuntu VM to the internet, and installing and configuring something like xrdp, you won't be able to do this either I'm afraid. Bastion demands using a browser, and it's RDP for Windows and SSH for Linux.
